# XQuery locate attribute by node value

Tags: attributes, xquery

I have a bunch of nodes like this:

```
<root>
   <books>
      <book id="1">Book 1</book>
      <book id="2">Book 2</book>
      <book id="3">Book 3</book>
   </books>
</root>
```

What I want is to get the id of the book with text node "Book 2". How do I do this? I tried this without any result ($doc is my document path):

```
let $b := $doc/root/books/book[book = "Book 2"]
return data($b/@id)
```

EDIT: I meant that $doc is the document node, not only the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `$doc` is in fact a *document-node* and not a *document path* as you described it then you can use the following:

```
$doc/root/books/book[. = "Book 2"]/data(@id)
```

Simply put `.` refers to the current context item, which is already book as that is the last part of the XPath before the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

if `$doc` is your document path, you'll need to call `fn:doc($doc)`, to get the document-node:

```
fn:doc($doc)/root/books/book[. = "Book 2"]/data(@id)
```